# Updating Visual Studio screws up Programs shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut, updates, startmenu

First, I do apologize if this question has been asked and answered before. (I am capable of internet searching but simply cannot find an answer anywhere!)

The (recurring) problem is that whenever I do a Windows Update that includes Visual Studio (2010) components (service packs, security updates, whatever), it auto-magically screws up my program shortcuts in the start menu.

If this isn't clear, I keep a folder called "Programming" (i.e. Start->All Programs->Programming). This is where I shove all the folders having to do with--what else--programming. MS SQL Server is there, there's a Ruby folder there, etc. (And, of course, MS VS 2010 stuff.)

Any MS VS updates recreate all of the shortcuts under "All Programs".
I have always just merged the folders (after cursing loudly several times).
Is there any way around this? Some registry tweak? Am I the only dummy that is irritated by this?